# In Ruby on Rails, why does a script match /something([^<]+)/ perfectly, but match the </td> also when it is the "script/runner" mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I tried a simple script with

```
arr = data.scan /<td>([^<]+)/
```

and the arr is filled with the data within the `<td>` and `</td>` when it is run using

```
ruby try.rb
```

but when it is run using

```
ruby script/runner app/try.rb
```

so that it is run just like inside of `script/console`, then now there is an extra `</td>` attached to the matched data...  Why would that be?  It is Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 2.3.8.  Would it be due to unicode in the app environment or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I would leave this as a comment because it doesn't really answer anything but I can't, I'm new around here and I guess I don't have the rep to do so, please excuse me.

I mocked the setup, used ruby 1.8.7 with an fully functional app on rails 2.3.8 and both times I got the proper output without the trailing  you mention. Now I am curious as to what's in data ? I used a generic table into a pretty simple html document. Works as it should.

One last thing worth mentioning maybe, regex to parse html is it a good idea ? I never had the need to use it but hpricot looks pretty neat for just that sort of thing http://github.com/hpricot/hpricot.

Hope this helps at least a little.

Comment: ah, that page that had problem had Big5 + ASCII in it... although it shouldn't have worked in non-runner mode and worked differently in runner mode...  unless the encoding was handled somewhat differently.